# Java: Running console commands and keeping the console running for further console commands

Tags: java, process, console, pipe, stdin

Sorry for the bad worded question, it is not that easy..

1. I need to run a console command but instead of just calling it using System.exec I need to access that process later.
2. So I decided to go with the `ProcessBuilder`

   `List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
   commands.add("cmd.exe"); //setting up what shell is used
   commands.add("/c");
   commands.add(commandString); //adding the actual command
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
   Process running = pb.start();`

   3. How can I keep writing to that same shell? So when I call multiple commands they are not executed in new shells but in the same one. This is necessary because someone might use commands like CD that change the result for further inputs.

*Example:
Executing: CD and dir/ls in one shell is different than calling two shell instances.*

4. I would like to be able to use pipe as well, which is not possible using I or II (for me at least)

Solution must work on windows and linux. I am very glad for any help someone can offer.
Someone did a tutorial online:
https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-system-command-pipeline-pipe

but it looks a bit ... cumbersome

Thanks guys

P.D.
I think the easiest solution is to somehow write into the shell directly. But right now I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: You need to learn about the difference between a "process" and a "shell" (you call it "console")

Comment: I apologize. I know the difference between process and shell, I have written one myself once and I am familiar with processes and threads in general. If the question is unclear please be more precise.

Comment: What is the nature of the command? Does the command work on both windows and linux?  Is it really necessary to execute via a `Process`?  Can you use java.io or java.nio (which would be OS compatible)?

Comment: It is not necessary to execute via  a Process, thought it would be the only feasible solution. The command is not defined and can be everything. It is a client input which then is executed at the server. When connecting to the server, the server will tell the client which shell he is using. The Client then can type in any commands and gets the response.

I can use java.io and java.nio.

Comment: Do you want to have an SSH-like server to work on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: @MartinB. yes; we are currently exploring the option of working with Input and Output-Streams